# Storing Values in an Array from Textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've been trying to experiment in a way in which i can store values entered from a textbox into an array.(using JavaScript or JQuery)

I understand I can do it this way:

`var array = [];
    var input = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
    array.push(input);`

But the functionality that I want to achieve is to be able to give the user an option to choose which array they want to save their input to.

Summary:

- How can a user choose which array to store the input text to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an object with keys as the options you want to give to the user and its value as array.

```
{'opt1':[],'opt2':[],...}
```

When the user selects his option get that array and `obj['opt'].push(inputValue)`. If the option does not exist then initialize a new array `obj['someKey'] = []` and start pushing into it

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That seems like it may be the solution